# How can I filter parts of a String that are formatted as a Date?

Tags: kotlin

I have a list of Strings containing names followed by a date:

```
"Name 1    2019 May 21 17:19:58"
"Name 2    2019 Jul 18 23:00:10"
```

All dates have the same pattern `yyyy MMM dd HH:mm:ss`.
I want to remove the dates so that only the names remain.
How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a regex:

```
   val s1 = "Name 1    2019 May 21 17:19:58"
       
   val a = s1.replace("\\d{4}.{3}[A-Za-z].\\d{2}.\\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2}".toRegex(), "")
```

Playground:

https://pl.kotl.in/O1PpgYfIU

Answer (score 1):

Since all the dates have the same format `yyyy MMM dd HH:mm:ss`, you can get all the chars of the string minus the last `20` chars which is the length of the dates.

You can do this with `substring()`:

```
val name = s.substring(0, s.length - 20).trim()
```

or with `take()`:

```
val name = s.take(s.length - 20).trim()
```

where `s` is your string.